# Dynamically find localstorage key using jQuery

Tags: jquery, local-storage, dry

I am trying to work out a way to DRY up the following code, which looks to see if certain local storage keys are present, then does something if they are. It could have many keys, but they will all be numbered to marry to the relevant element id, i.e, key: item1 > #item1 etc.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('item1')) {
  $('#item1').addClass('active');
}

if (localStorage.getItem('item2')) {
  $('#item2').addClass('active');
}

etc.
```

I recently learned to do something similar with element id's, so I was wondering if / how I could apply this type of logic to finding local storage key's instead of element id's?

```
$('*[id^=btn-item]').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').slice(-1); 
  $('#item'+id).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: do you need to do this for every key in `localStorage` or only for some specific key that's known in advance (perhaps because you clicked on an element with a corresponding name) ?

Comment: There will be certain keys present, but not known specifically. I need to be able to say... if there are any keys available, apply their numeric value to a element with the same numeric value at the end of their id. This need to be able to work on a couple of different pages. Hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (correctly) iterate over the possible keys in `localStorage` without knowing in advance what the maximum possible key number is:

```
var re = /^item\d+$/;
for (var i = 0, n = localStorage.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    if (re.test(key)) {
       $('#' + key).addClass('active');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, reverse the logic and look in the DOM first:

```
$('[id^="item"]').addClass(function() {
    return localStorage.getItem(this.id) ? "active" : "";
});
```

Comment: With a reasonably full localStorage do you seriously think this would be more efficient than testing 100 keys ?

Comment: We don't know how full the OP's localStorage is.  The real point is that you should never use a hard-coded limit.  In any event, the second code I just added is probably better than both.

Comment: @dystroy look again - it's nothing like it.  My second code iterates over each potentially matching DOM node using a CSS selector and _then_ tests whether the matching element exists in `localStorage`.

Comment: I've read my answer again and you're right. I thought I had proposed it but I forgot to put it between the one with the click handler and the loop. This is the way to go. Slower for sure but cleaner.

Comment: @dystroy actually I doubt it's slower - on a modern browser the CSS selector will be handled directly and efficiently in the browser and it's then a simple case of checking whether the ID exists in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the slice code only works if your id is smaller than 10.

For greater id I would suggest `$(this).attr('id').slice("btn-item".length);` which gets `324` from `"btm-item324"`.

This being said, why not just doing this ?

```
$('*[id^=btn-item]').click(function () {
  var id = $(this).attr('id').slice("btn-item".length); 
  if (localStorage.getItem('item'+id)) {
     $('#item'+id).addClass('active');
  }
}
```

If you don't want to do this on a button action, you can iterate on the possible keys like this :

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
   if (localStorage['item'+i]) $('#item'+i).addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: @Alnitak I doesn't iterate over all the keys, it just test the ones of the specified format. Do you have a more efficient solution to check those keys ? There is no query language for localStorage.

Comment: Cheers, but I need to be able to apply this to different pages. The click function I provided there was just to illustrate how I thought I could tackle this.

btw. Thanks for the heads-up of the slice thing which hadn't occurred to me. I guess I would have noticed eventually, so your tip will be handy!

Comment: @dystroy Perfect, that does exactly what I need. Loops have never been my strongpoint, but I can kind of understand that. Many thanks :)

Comment: @Jamie note that if you ever have more than 100 keys, this will fail.  Similarly it inefficiently tries to test for 100 keys, even if there's only 5 in the list...

Comment: @Alnitak thanks. Presumably I could change the i<100 value if I know the amount of items.

Comment: @Jamie you could, but it's still not a great design